# Как взять данные из массива и положить на mapview?

Tags: массивы, objective-c, карты, mapview

Здравствуйте.
Не могу разобраться как взять данные с массива и положить их на карту.
Написал такой вариант:

```
  MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];


    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    NSMutableArray *newAnnotations = [NSMutableArray array];
    MKPointAnnotation *newAnnotation;


    for (NSDictionary *dict in shops_array){
        location.latitude = [dict[@"lat"] doubleValue];
        location.longitude = [dict[@"lng"] doubleValue];

        newAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        newAnnotation.coordinate = location;
        [newAnnotations addObject:newAnnotation];


    }

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
```

Не работает. Буду благодарен если поможете.

Answer (score 0):

Вы создаете пустой массив, затем объявляете `MKPointAnnotation`, в цикле инициализируете ее с новыми координатами и добавляете в массив, а затем добавляете на карту не массив, а последнюю `MKPointAnnotation`.

Хотя даже если массив добавите, отобразится не то что хотите. Попробуйте:

```
NSMutableArray *arrAnnotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *dict in shops_array){
    MKPointAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    newAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([dict[@"lat"] doubleValue], [dict[@"lng"] doubleValue]);
    [arrAnnotations addObject:newAnnotation];
}

[self.mapView addAnnotations:arrAnnotations];
```

Comment: спасибо за код. Я просто не могу понять как вытаскивать из массива координаты и ложить их на карту. То что выше - я пробую. Выбивает ошибку что: 

'-[__NSSingleObjectArrayI doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800000a310'
Я так понимаю - это связано с разными типами данных. В итоговых координатах double, у меня хранятся строки.
Смотрел штук 20 мануалов по созданию mapView. Как-то там всё шаблонно.

Comment: @VladislavHodeev что у Вас в shops_array? Если так посмотреть, сейчас вряд ли можно найти что-то не шаблонное. И не только в программах.

Comment: coordinate (
        (
                (
            "-74.009427600000000"
        ),
                (
            "<null>"
        ),
                (
            "-74.150420400000000"
        )
    ),
        (
                (
            "40.706808900000000"
        ),
                (
            "<null>"
        ),
                (
            "40.553503900000000"
        )
    )
)
Вот содержимое массива.

Comment: @VladislavHodeev  И где здесь NSDictionary? Как складываются данные в массив?

Comment: в первом классе я их забираю из JSON, нарезаю в массив. Этот массив через синглтон передаю в массив второго класса.shops_array собственно.

Comment: @VladislavHodeev значит складываете данные не в том виде. Должен же быть dictionary, если так хотите разобрать.

Comment: а каким образом их разобрать через массив?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
[self.mapView addAnnotations:arrAnnotations];
```